# How do I give access to only owner to call the function?

Tags: solidity, remix

How do I give access to only owner to call the function? As when I try this code owner is not able to access or else both owner as well as others are able to access the function.

```
 modifier _ownerOnly(){
      
   require(msg.sender == owner);
   _;

 }


  function getAllUsers()public view _ownerOnly returns (address[], string[], string[], string[], string[]){


    address[] memory wallet_addresses = new address[](registeredArray.length);
    string[]  memory _ids = new string[](registeredArray.length);
    string[] memory firstNames = new string[](registeredArray.length);
    string[] memory lastNames = new string[](registeredArray.length);
    string[] memory emailIds = new string[](registeredArray.length);
    
    for (uint i = 0; i < registeredArray.length; i++) {
        
        wallet_addresses[i] = registeredArray[i].wallet_address;
        _ids[i] = registeredArray[i].userId;
        firstNames[i] = registeredArray[i].first_name;
        lastNames[i] = registeredArray[i].last_name;
        emailIds[i] = registeredArray[i].email_id;
        
    }
    
    return (wallet_addresses, _ids, firstNames, lastNames, emailIds);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the modifier on your function like so.

```
address owner;

 modifier onlyOwner() {
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    _;
}

constructor(address _owner){
owner = _owner;
}


function MyOwnedFunction(address arg1, uint arg2) public onlyOwner {
  // do things only Owner can do here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `owner` variable needs to be set to whatever address you would like before you can use it.

You could potentially just hardcode in whatever address you wanted, for example:

```
address public owner = 0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4;
```

But a common convention is to set your owner variable inside your contract's constructor so that it is equal to the address that deployed the contract.

Which would look something like this:

```
address public owner;

constructor () {
  owner = msg.sender;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract yourcontract is Ownable {
   //here no need declare **address owner** its declared on Owneable extenesion

   construct() {}

   function showOwner() public view returns(address) {
      return Ownable.owner();
   }

}
```

Hope helps.
Regards